# Display error when input field is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a view that allows user to add new items to a database.

The view looks like this:

```
@model News.Models.NewsEntry

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>NewsEntry</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.body, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.body)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.body)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.category, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.category)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Can I write some function (if sentance) inside my view that checks if the title input or the body input are empty and displays a message if they are.**

My attempt so far:
**EDIT:**

Comment: Just curious, what's wrong with ValidationMessageFor that you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP MVC this should be done on the model, decorate the property using `Required` attribute

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required!")]
public string title { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Body is required !")]
public string body { get; set; }
```

You will need to add following namespace:

[using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

I created a [project](https://mega.co.nz/#!fcQgVQZS!0GwEzV0KKm8zESRtdTs4IIwahA5qf8jek7dD3qelUJ0) for you.

Try it its very simple:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I have to include some using.system.xxx to be able to use the required attribute?

Comment: @user3265963 yes I believe you need `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Comment: I changed my Model as you suggested. Check my edit... Should this be enough so it will display a message when I try to create a new item with empty body or title? It is at least not working. It creates it even though the body or title is missing

Comment: @user3265963 yes that's all you need , what do you have in your controller, what is your model name `NewsEntry` ?

Comment: In your controller you sould check your model with "ModelState.IsValid"

Comment: I added the controller for create in my OP. And yes it name is Newsentry

Comment: Thanks for the sample program. It worked fine and I understand it.. However I still haven't got mine to work. I feel like I am doing exactly the same thing as in your sample program. I've edited my post and added the Model, View and Controller as they are now.